# What "additional voices" did Alison Viktorin voice in Fullmetal Alchemist?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, voice-acting

As the title suggests, she is only credited for "additional voices"

http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1516108/

However, one of the shows she is "known for" is FMA Brotherhood. I feel like her voice is familiar from FMA so I was wondering if anyone could tell me who the "additional voices" are?

Comment: I think she's only "known for" it because it's a big-name title that she was "additional voices" in. She did not voice any major role. As for which voices she did, I'm unsure.

Comment: IMDb's "known for" algorithm doesn't know how important somebody was in a movie or TV series, so it's likely on her list just because FMA brotherhood is one of the more popular and recent things she's been in. Detective Conan is first because she was in over a hundred episodes, but everything after that are just guesses made by an automated system.

Answer (score 4):

IMDb is mistaken in that Alison Viktorin is "known for" *Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood*. As was stated in the comments. IMDb simply sees that Viktorin did voice work for *Brotherhood*, sees that *Brotherhood* is a very famous title, and assumes that she is well-known for her work in it.

This is quite contrary to the truth, though. Viktorin is credited only as "additional voices" in one episode: episode 43. I've seen the episode a few times, and can confirm that there are only four places where a non-credited voice (i.e. one outside the named cast in the credits) is heard (excluding obviously male voices):

- Two children laughing and playing (2:35)
- Child grabbing Yoki's hair (3:03)
- Baby tugging on sleeve (10:14)
- Unintelligible chattering and whispering (11:01)

Though I can't tell which one of these four instances Viktorin actually voices, all four are very minor roles that are hardly worthy of mention.